# Python docx : How to extract tables between two fixed strings from mutiple word files

Tags: python, python-docx

Suppose i have multiple word files in a format like this

String 1
 table 1
 table 2
String 2
 table 3
 table 4
String 3
 table 5

I need to extract table between "String 2" and "String 3" i.e. table 3 and table 4. How can i extract table cell values

Comment: can't you read the tables you want with pandas?

Comment: I used docx library to read tables from .docx file, but it work well when i know the position of the table but here i need to get all table present between two string. I havn't tried with pandas. Please let me know if i could achieve that?

Comment: i dont understand what you mean, if each table is a separate file, you can read them with `pd.read_csv`